# "So...that" sentences

Tags: grammar

One could say:
I was so tired that I slept for ten hours.

You could also say:
I was so tired, I slept for ten hours.

The second one is more colloquial I think, but is it acceptable grammatically?  If so, is a comma the correct use of punctuation there, or does it have to be a semi-colon maybe?  Or no punctuation at all?

Comment: So...that establishes a cause and effect linkage that sentence 2 lacks.

Comment: The cause and effect wouldn't be implied?

Comment: Well, if you changed it to "I was so tired, I ran a marathon" then the cause and effect are reversed!  It is a weaker linkage than the first one.

Comment: @Oldcat: Very good point. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Oldcat, “I was so tired, I ran a marathon” does not compute for me. The tenses matching up forces my brain to perceive the two as cause and effect. What I think you're trying to say would to me have to have different tenses, and would also require more than just a comma to separate the two clauses: “I was so tired: I'd run a marathon”. In the askers example, the conjunction _that_ is simply being left out, which is perfectly valid and in no way changes the structure or meaning of the sentence, -->

Comment: --> so I see no reason a comma should be added: “I was so tired I went straight to bed” is perfectly fine. I'm not even sure I'd label it colloquial—only, perhaps, slightly less formal.

Comment: @Janus - consider that the word in my sentence left out is 'because', not 'that'. It is just a weaker formulation, not an incorrect one.

Comment: @Oldcat, yes, I understood that. But even with it back in, “I was so tired because I ran a marathon” is _very_ unnatural to me, unless we make up rather fanciful contexts to force it to fit (“No wonder I was always nodding off and had no energy—I was so tired because I ran a marathon three times a week!”). In any normal context that I can think of, the two clauses cannot both be in the simple past if the latter shouldn't be seen as a general statement.

Comment: @Janus - it isn't that unnatural - you are allowed to enlarge upon a statement with the next one.  In both cases, the lack of linking words to define the relationship between the two halves of the sentence makes it weaker and harder to understand.  Thus I suggest that you put those words in and remove the issue altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any grammatical problem with either sentence, but the first sentence

> I was so tired that I slept for ten hours.

has a more specific structure that is saying that the first clause **caused** the second one.  The comma is a weaker linkage, as this change shows.

> I was so tired, I ran a marathon.

Here, the second clause is the cause of the first one, and cause and effect are reversed. If you wanted the same thought made more clear, as in the first sentence, you could add 'because'.

> I was so tired because I ran a marathon.

Answer (score 1):

The second is neither less grammatical, nor more colloquial (it's found throughout the English-speaking world).

It is though sometimes less clear, in that it leaves the link between the clauses to be deduced. This is fine in your example, but consider:

> I was so angry, I cut myself chopping vegetables.

Here we could reasonably interpret this as:

> I was so angry that I then I cut myself chopping vegetables.

(Presumably my anger leading to a loss of concentration).

Or:

> I was so angry because I cut myself chopping vegetables.

Since one could reasonably interpret the sentence either way, it doesn't suit most uses (there are times when one wants ambiguity and multivalency, but usually it helps clear communication to avoid it).

Your example though doesn't suffer from this, and is fine.

Comment: Adding _that_ doesn't really fix the ambiguity, though. “I was so angry that I cut my finger that I couldn't concentrate afterwards and cut my other finger too”. But that's more a property of _angry_, which can take a relative clause as complement.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yeah, and I ended up having to resolve further. I shall hopefully think of a better example soon.