# Is it "so ..." or "so that ..."?

Tags: that

I am sorry if this has been asked before.

I read the following in a textbook:

> The examples are intentionally simple, so we can focus on the language features.

I thought that

> The examples are intentionally simple so *that* we can focus on the language features.

is correct.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: You’re right that the second version is correct, but why would there be only one correct way to do something? Human language almost never works that way. Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16883, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/148533, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1095

Comment: Thanks @tchrist. It appears that the question Hank pointed me to seems to resolve the confusion. In the context of the paragraph, it appears that not only _so that ..._ is correct, but _so ..._ is wrong.

Comment: Your two sentences ***can*** both mean the same thing as each other means. I would not call it “wrong”, whatever that means.

Comment: The accepted answer on the original question says that _so that ..._ is used to specify the _reason_ of some action. My understanding of the paragraph in the textbook gives me the same impression. Hence, I thought that _so that..._ (and not _so..._ ) is required there.

Comment: The two versions of *“I did it so we could leave”*  and *“I did it so **that** we could leave”* mean quite exactly the same thing and neither is wrong: that *that* is completely optional and changes nothing.  On the other hand, by adding the comma in *“I did it, so now we can leave”*, this means something else altogether, and that version does not allow a *that*. That's the important difference. But there are no commas in speech, so you have to learn to perceive both possibilities by context.

Comment: Let's leave it at that so that we can avoid rather long discussion threads.